# How to sliding layout in service?

Tags: android, layout, service, slide

I'm doing a service application. Service is running, and can sense the touch. This service
application, how do add a slide layout in service?

I did a lot of research on this topic and have found solutions often has failed.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
public class SidebarService extends Service implements View.OnTouchListener {

private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private LinearLayout touchLayout;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    touchLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(30,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    Log.i(TAG, "add View");
    mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mWindowManager != null) {
        if (touchLayout != null) mWindowManager.removeView(touchLayout);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {// || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        Toast.makeText(this, "slide", Toast.LENGTH.SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Service is not supposed to sense touch. You are doing things fundamentally wrong. refer developer.android.com to learn about services and their application

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, but it does not help me. I do not know much english. If I find sample code, maybe I can solve. Thanks...

Comment: to draw something above all windows. check this link this might be helpful to you http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/